# How to configure a pre-existing image with Docker Compose

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I have an app that uses the MySQL image, and I need to supply to configure its `bind-address`. What is the best way of doing this? I have tried creating a file `mysqld.cnf` containing the below information, but can’t seem to get this working using the below code. You can see from the versions this is an old application, should that make a difference.

When starting the server, I still see:

```
[Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
```

Is there either a way to make the below work, or another way to configure MySQL's bind-address?

**mysqld.cnf:**

```
[mysqld]
bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - devdb:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mysql.cnf:/etc/mysqld/conf.d/mysqld.cnf
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'pi3'
      MYSQL_USER: 'dev'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'dev'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root'
    ports:
      - "33312:3306"
  app:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - ./node_modules:/usr/src/app/node_modules
      - ./logs:/usr/src/app/logs
      - ${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}:/ssh-agent
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - DATABASE_NAME=collabor8
      - DATABASE_HOST=db
      - DATABASE_USERNAME=root
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=root
      - SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/ssh-agent

volumes:
  devdb:
```

Comment: Why is there a need to configure the bind-address? Your App can talk to db:3306. No need to publish the MySQL Server to the Host (on port 33312).

Comment: I'm having strange errors, and had the same error with the web server which I fixed by binding to 0.0.0.0. It probably isn't the best solution but it's an old app I'm just trying to get running in the first instance to then move on with.

Comment: My guess is that the my.cnf file mapped via Docker-compose volumes comes in too late in the process. The MySQL container already started. (Sorry, there must be a better way of explaining this. But this is how I explained it to myself :-) )
If you still want to do this, then only option would be to create your own MySQL Image with your my.cnf in it. 
Better to get those strange errors fixed. Even an old NodeJS application just 'connects' to a database somewhere. Another container (like MySQL) should not be of influence to this (old) App Container.